# Best practice to center a DIV right above a centralized DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I want to appear right in the middle of the screen.
above it I would like to have a short text, that I want to be in the center above that image.

I've managed to do it "manually" with a negative left margin, but is there a better way to do it?

Also, is the code ok in general?

HTML:

```
<div class="central">
<div class="msg">This Message needs to be in the center</div>
<img src="image.gif" width="130" height="15" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.central {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -(X/2)px;
    margin-top: -(Y/2)px;
}
.msg {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#03C;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:-70px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: "Best Practice" may not rely on facts. There are couple of ways to achieve that which have been discussed several times on SO, here's a good collection by Chris Coyier: http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
.msg {
   text-align:center;
   font-family:Arial;
   font-size:14px;
   color:#03C;
}

img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.central{
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: the image is not showing on the center this way... it's on the left

Comment: You can add a width to the div.

Comment: still doesn't work well, also, this method doesn't make it vertically aligned to the center as well, which is another requirement

Comment: Try out the new edit.

Comment: better now, but still not vertically aligned to the center :)

Comment: You can change margin-top as you wish. Try this out.

Comment: Ok so far this is the best answer, as it's working well also when the window is being resized. (with 15% margin though), thanks!

Comment: If it is the best answer I think you should accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with margin-bottom - 50% also:

```
img {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.central{
    margin-bottom: -50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="central">
<div class="msg">This Message needs to be in the center</div>
<img src="image.gif"  />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.central img{
     display:block;
     width: 130px;
     height:15px;
     position:relative;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="central">
    <div class="msg">This Message needs to be in the center</div>
    <img src="http://freedomdefined.org/upload/thumb/5/5c/Fd_sq_icon_sc.svg/64px-Fd_sq_icon_sc.svg.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.central {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:'x' px; //such that it is vertically in the middle
 }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dy5700ju/).